# DataGridview All column data into one Column

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one datagridview ,there are 5 columns.I want that 5 columns data in one column . Example:-

```
Datatable1      Datatable2

A   B   C   D   New Coln 
10  11  21  31  10
11  12  22  32  11
12  13  23  33  12
13  14  24  34  13
14  15  25  35  14
                11
                12
                13
                14
                15
                21
                22
                23
                24
                25
                31
                32
                33
                34
                35
```

Comment: where is the data coming from ? And how do you fill the DataGridView ?

Comment: Data coming from individual sql query to individual column

Comment: so you have a different sql query for each column ?

Comment: No,there is only one datatable with multiple columns which need to be pushed in new datatable in one column.

Comment: GuidoG : Yes ,different query for each column

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop will resolve this issue. see the output of the following

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("col4", typeof(int));

table.Rows.Add(25 ,10,2,10);
table.Rows.Add(22, 11, 12, 14);
table.Rows.Add(13, 22, 3, 55);
table.Rows.Add(3, 4, 12, 5);

DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
table2.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(int));

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
  foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
  {
    table2.Rows.Add(int.Parse((row[col].ToString())));
  }
}
```

Result

```
25
10
2
10
22
11
12
14
13
22
3
55
3
4
12
5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform this *operation* with using the source DataTable (not SQL), you can use LINQ to extact the Rows values by Column:

Naming **`dt1`** the source DataTable and **`dt2`** the destination DataTable:

```
var dt2 = new DataTable("DataTable2");
dt2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1") { DataType = typeof(int) });

dt1.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().SelectMany((col, idx) =>
    dt1.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(row => dt2.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray[idx]))).ToList();
```